# How to resolve the syntax error about </body> that I get using web.py?

Tags: python, html, web.py

I've been following [the tutorial on the web.py website](http://webpy.org/docs/0.3/tutorial) and I'm trying to get the html page working but I keep getting this error:

```
<type 'exceptions.SyntaxError'> at /
invalid syntax Template traceback:
File 'templates\\index.html', line 14 </body> (index.html, line 14)
```

And I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong (as I'm basicaly just copy/pasting the tutorial).

Here's the content of **index.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
    $def with (name)

    $if name:
        I just wanted to say <em>hello</em> to $name.
    $else:
        <em>Hello</em>, world!
</body>

</html>
```

And here's **code.py**:

```
import web

render = web.template.render('templates/')

urls = (
    '/', 'index'
)

class index:
    def GET(self):
        name = 'Bob'
        return render.index(name)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run()
```

Why is it saying there's a syntax error at `</body>`? Is the structure different with web.py?

Answer (score 0):

Try not usign html, head and body tags in templates.
So your code would look like this:

```
$def with (name)

$if name:
    I just wanted to say <em>hello</em> to $name.
$else:
    <em>Hello</em>, world!
```